# Using AngularJS $http to access Facebook Workplace Graph API

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I am using the Facebook workplace API for [posting to group feed](https://github.com/fbsamples/workplace-platform-samples/tree/master/FeedPoster). The sample code by Facebook uses *requestjs* for API calls, which is loaded via *RequireJS*. Below is the Workplace Graph API access code:

```
var feed = require('feed-read');
var request = require('request');

var graphapi = request.defaults({
    baseUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com',
    auth: {
        'bearer' : ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
});

graphapi({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/' + TARGET_GROUP + '/feed',
    qs: {
        'message': article.title,
        'link': article.link
    }
},function(error,response,body) {
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        var post_id = JSON.parse(body).id;
        console.log('Published "' + article.title + '": ' + post_id);
        last_check = Date.now();
    }
});
```

The issue is that I am using AngularJS setup that does not use RequireJS for module loading and I don't want to setup that. Also there is `$http` object for API calls provided by AngularJS, but can it be used to access the GraphAPI? How should I retrieve the `graphapi` that this code is using via `$http`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$http.post('https://graph.facebook.com/'+ TARGET_GROUP + '/feed', {
    'message': article.title,
    'link': article.link'
  }, {
    headers: {
      'bearer' : ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  },function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

Comment: Worked with modifications. Had to use query parameters instead of data property of $http, also header name would be`Authorization` and it's value will be `ACCESS_TOKEN`.